# Postgres vs SQL lite page not found discrapancy

Tags: django, postgresql

I have my dev environment with django - SQLlite and my prod is with django 
 - Postgres

I have view that works perfectly on SQL lite

```
login_required
def receipt_pdf(request,pk):

    try:
        Receipt_payment_id_dict = Receipt_payment.objects.filter(is_active = True ).aggregate(Max('id'))
        if Receipt_payment_id_dict:
            Receipt_payment_id =  Receipt_payment_id_dict['id__max'] 
            Receipt_payment_dict = get_object_or_404(Receipt_payment, pk=Receipt_payment_id)      
        else:
            Receipt_payment_dict = "no data"
    except ValueError:
        raise Http404("At least one active value should be in -Receipt_payment-, contact your administrator")


    try:
        general_id_dict = General_configurations.objects.filter(is_active = True ).aggregate(Max('id'))
        if general_id_dict:
            general_id =  general_id_dict['id__max']
            general_dict = get_object_or_404(General_configurations, pk=general_id)
        else:
            general_dict = "no data"
    except ValueError:
        raise Http404("At least one active value should be in -General_configurations-, contact your administrator")


    payment = get_object_or_404(LeasePayment, pk=pk)
   # leasetenant = lease.tenant_set.all().order_by('-id')

    # Create the HttpResponse object with the appropriate PDF headers.
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="Receipt.pdf"'

    buffer = BytesIO()

    # Create the PDF object, using the BytesIO object as its "file."
    p = canvas.Canvas(buffer)
```

But When I execute same code with Postgres I get

> No Receipt_payment matches the given query.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Well, *do* you have data in Postgres that matches that query?

Comment: Yes I do. Checked 4 times.I basically create  payment and then I create receipt for this payment . Difficult to miss.

Comment: Why use sqlite in dev and postgres in production? The Django ORM should be database agnostic, but sqlite and postgres are different. Why the complex aggregrate? `Receipt_payment.objects.filter(is_active=True).order_by('id').last()`.